# How to get multiple parameters including spaces with wmic (cmd commandline)?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, escaping, wmic

The volume name of my drive C: is `300GB WD3000HLFS-0` (including a space between '300GB' and 'WD3000HLFS-0')
The volume serial number of C: is `1234-ABCD`
(according to the command `VOL`)

I'm not successful with this code:

```
SET WMICcmd="WMIC logicaldisk WHERE VolumeSerialNumber='1234ABCD' get Caption^,VolumeName^,VolumeSerialNumber^"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 skip=1" %%d IN (' %WMICcmd% ')  DO (

ECHO '%%d' is the Drive with the VolumeName '%%e' and VolumeSerialNumber '%%f'
SET ODrive=%%d
)
```

How can I get this VolumeName with the help of WMIC and with a specific VolumeSerialNumber in a Windows 7 commandline batch in addition to other parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a CSV output format, one line with all the properties separated with commas

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %%a in (
        'WMIC logicaldisk WHERE VolumeSerialNumber^="1234ABCD" get Caption^,VolumeName^,VolumeSerialNumber /format:csv'
    ) do (
        ECHO '%%a' is the Drive with the VolumeName '%%b' and VolumeSerialNumber '%%c'
    )
```

But if any of the fields contain a comma, it will fail, so, you can use a list format. In this case, the output of the wmic command is one line for each of the requested properties, in the format `property=value`.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in (
        'WMIC logicaldisk WHERE VolumeSerialNumber^="1234ABCD" get Caption^,VolumeName^,VolumeSerialNumber /format:list'
    ) do (
        if "%%a"=="Caption" ( set "caption=%%b"
        ) else if "%%a"=="VolumeName" ( set "volumeName=%%b"
        ) else if "%%a"=="VolumeSerialNumber" ( set "volumeSerialNumber=%%b"
        )
    )
    ECHO '%caption%' is the Drive with the VolumeName '%volumeName%' and VolumeSerialNumber '%volumeSerialNumber%'
```

WMIC output includes an aditional carriage return at the end of each output line and this aditional character gets stored inside the assigned variables. Depending of your code, it can interfer or not. If necessary, to remove this aditional character all that is need is

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%caption%") do set "caption=%%a"
```

This will reassign the same value to the variable but without the aditional CR